# Calling function from T4 text templating file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, texttemplate

I am using T4 tt file in which i am trying to call a function table ,which is in the different namespace and class say r2ts and sql respectively..

i had imported the namespace and making call like below

```
<#@ import namespace= "r2ts" #>

<# 
   WriteLine(r2ts.sql.GetTable(schema, tablename));
#>
```

it is not working it error like below

compilation transformaton: The Type or Namespace name r2ts could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

any work around plz.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to reference the dll and also the assembly directive

```
<#@ assembly name="Name of the assembly" #>
```

...check [this](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-assembly-directive/)

Comment: <#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" #>   had added it even though same error

Comment: Not like this...add this <#@ assembly name="System.Core" #> and also add a reference like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: what all we can add that way is the namespace that we are going to use which nothing but r2ts . so thats already in there....

Comment: I think r2ts is a namespace, now "An Assembly can contain many namespaces. A dll is an assembly". You can change the assembly name as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f0c12ze9(v=vs.100).aspx